# I can't log into my Mac Due to a repair issue in home folder

Tags: mac, operating-systems, xorg

How can you log in as a different user if it won't let you log in at all due to an error opening the home folder protected by fire vault?

Answer (score 1):

Dear Drambler: This is a common issue among Mac users come across for a while,

Start up from OS X Recovery.
For such, you can just press Command R while starting up your Mac. Keep holding on until you see the circle that begins to load OS X Recovery. Let go your hold and wait till Mac OS X Utilities begin.

Click on Disk Utility. Select the drive partition where OS X has been installed. Click on Unlock and provide password because your disk is protected by Vault.

Now, you are ready to Verify Disk, Repair Disk, Verify Disk Permissions and also Repair Disk Permissions. You would like to do one at a time. Once alls done. You're done.

Quit Disk Utility, quit Mac OS X Utilities, and hit Restart. You will be good my friend.

Good luck!........Also,
you can refer the following guides which are already available online in different technology supporting forums bellow. If it was not sufficient to solve with just let me know :)

1. [Home folder permissions repair in OS X](http://www.cnet.com/news/home-folder-permissions-repair-in-os-x/)
2. [Why can't I login? OS X with FileVault enabled](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/241277/Why+can't+I+login+OS+X+with+FileVault+enabled)
3. [OS X: Repair Home Folder Permissions](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/os-x-repair-home-folder-permissions)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sure I have edited my answer :) Thanks for the suggestion.